# How to sort collection_select drop-down menu which consists of strings with numbers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a Rails (4.1.8) / Ruby (2.1.5) application. I have the following collection_select form field:

```
 <%= f.collection_select :target_ids, Target.order(:outcome), :id, :outcome, { :prompt => "-- Select one to two --" }, { :multiple => true, :size => 6 } %>
```

This works as expected, but I need help sorting the order of items in the drop-down menu, which consists of strings with numbers.  My current code sorts the list in ascending order by letter but the numbers in the strings are out of order.  Here's a snippet to show what the menu looks like now:

```
-- Select one to two -- 
Gain 10 pounds
Gain 15 pounds
Gain 1 pound
Lose 10 pounds
Lose 15 pounds
Lose 1 pound
Reduce body fat by 15%
Reduce body fat by 2%
```

Here's how I want to sort the menu:

```
-- Select one to two --
Gain 1 pound
Gain 10 pounds
Gain 15 pounds
Lose 1 pound
Lose 10 pounds
Lose 15 pounds
Reduce body fat by 2%
Reduce body fat by 15%
```

How do I get the numbers in the strings to display in the order I want?  Is there a Ruby sort method that handles this kind of sort out-of-the -box, or do I need to write a custom sort method?  How do I best achieve the result I'm looking for?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use `Enumerable#sort_by` with a block that extracts the leading text and the digits (converted to Fixnums) from each `outcome`:

```
class Target < ActiveRecord::Base
  OUTCOME_PARTS_EXPR = /(\D+)(\d+)/

  # ...

  def self.sort_by_outcome
    all.sort_by do |target|
      outcome = target.outcome
      next [ outcome ] unless outcome =~ OUTCOME_PARTS_EXPR
      [ $1, $2.to_i ]
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in your controller:

```
@targets_sorted = Target.sort_by_outcome
```

And, finally, in your view:

```
<%= f.collection_select :target_ids, @targets_sorted, :id, :outcome,
      { :prompt => "-- Select one to two --" }, { :multiple => true, :size => 6 } %>
```

### How it works

In general you should try to do all of your sorting in the database, but since I don't know what database you're using I'm going to limit my answer to how to do this in Ruby. With relatively few records the performance penalty will be negligible anyway—premature optimization and all that.

In Ruby the [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) method will sort an Enumerable by the result of a block. It looks like you want to sort your values first by the part before the digits (e.g. `"Gain "`, `"Reduce body fat by "`) and then by the integer value of the digits (e.g. the Fixnum `10` instead of the string `"10"`). Let's break it into steps:

#### 1. Get the desired parts from the string.

This is easy with a regular expression:

```
OUTCOME_PARTS_EXPR = /(\D+)(\d+)/
str = "Gain 10 pounds"
str.match(OUTCOME_PARTS_EXPR).captures
# => [ "Gain ", "10" ]
```

Note: This regular expression assumes that there will *always* be some non-digit text before the digits. If that's not the case this may need some modification.

#### 2. Do it to every element in an Enumerable

Using `Enumerable#map` we can do it for a whole Enumerable, and while we're at it we can convert the digits to Fixnums (e.g. `"10"` to `10`):

```
arr = [
  "Gain 10 pounds",
  "Gain 15 pounds",
  "Gain 1 pound",
  "Lose 10 pounds",
  "Lose 15 pounds",
  "Lose 1 pound",
  "Reduce body fat by 15%",
  "Reduce body fat by 2%"
]

arr.map do |str|
  next [ str ] unless str =~ OUTCOME_PARTS_EXPR
  [ $1, $2.to_i ]
end
```

The block we're passing to `map` does two things: If the string doesn't match our regular expression it just returns the string (as a single-element array). Otherwise, it returns an array with the first capture (`"Gain "`) as a string and the second capture (`10`) as a Fixnum. This is the result:

```
[ [ "Gain ", 10 ],
  [ "Gain ", 15 ],
  [ "Gain ",  1 ],
  [ "Lose ", 10 ],
  [ "Lose ", 15 ],
  [ "Lose ",  1 ],
  [ "Reduce body fat by ", 15 ],
  [ "Reduce body fat by ",  2 ] ]
```

#### 3. Sort by those parts

Now that we know how to get the parts we need, we can pass the same block to `sort_by` to sort by them:

```
arr.sort_by do |str|
  next [ str ] unless str =~ OUTCOME_PARTS_EXPR
  [ $1, $2.to_i ]
end
# => [ "Gain 1 pound",
#      "Gain 10 pounds",
#      "Gain 15 pounds",
#      "Lose 1 pound",
#      "Lose 10 pounds",
#      "Lose 15 pounds",
#      "Reduce body fat by 2%",
#      "Reduce body fat by 15%" ]
```

Great! But there's one last step...

#### 4. Do it to a collection returned by an ActiveRecord query

We're not sorting an array of strings, we're sorting a collection of `Target` objects. This isn't much of a complication, though; we just need to point to the right attribute, i.e. `outcome`:

```
Target.all.sort_by do |target|
  outcome = target.outcome
  next [ outcome ] unless outcome =~ OUTCOME_PARTS_EXPR
  [ $1, $2.to_i ]
end
```

Note that I changed `Target.order(:outcome)` to `Target.all`. Since we're sorting in Ruby it probably doesn't make sense to also sort in the database query.

#### 5. All together now

To clean things up, you should probably put this in your Target model, e.g.:

```
class Target < ActiveRecord::Base
  OUTCOME_PARTS_EXPR = /(\D+)(\d+)/

  # ...

  def self.sort_by_outcome
    all.sort_by do |target|
      outcome = target.outcome
      next [ outcome ] unless outcome =~ OUTCOME_PARTS_EXPR
      [ $1, $2.to_i ]
    end
  end
end
```

As a class method you can call this like `Target.sort_by_outcome`, or you can put it on the end of a query like `Target.where(...).sort_by_outcome`. So in your case you'd want to put this in the controller (as a rule of thumb you should never do ActiveRecord queries in your view):

```
@targets_sorted = Target.sort_by_outcome
```

...and then in your view you'll use `@targets_sorted` instead of `Target.order(:outcome)`.

Comment: Dear downvoter: Please leave a comment explaining the reason for your downvote. If my answer is lacking I would love the opportunity to improve it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think I'm following what you're suggesting regarding Enumerable#sort_by.  However, I'm struggling to figure out what code I need to put in my Target model, controller and view to implement your recommended solution.  Can you clarify.  Sorry for the request for more direction; I'm still in learning mode with Ruby/Rails.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain where you can put this code in your model and then how to use it in your controller and view (see **5. All together now**).

Comment: thanks for your recommendation; I managed to get the sort working in the manner desired.  I will accept your answer. I appreciate your detailed explanation and patience.